# Solve birthday problem with probability theory and combinatorics

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I got the following problem:

How many persons have to be in a room so the probability that at least two persons have birthday in the same month is over 50%.

Through trying out I figured there have to be at least 5 persons in the room for a probability over 50% (for 5 people it would be exactly 62%):

$$
1-\frac {12*11*10*9*8} {12*12*12*12*12} = 0,62
$$

I heard there is a direct way to compute this through probability theory (where every month has the same probability to be a birth month) and there is another way through combinatorics. Is this correct?

Comment: The way you computed was direct, wasn't it? What do you mean by direct?

Comment: Done many times here, full results on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

Comment: that *is* how you solve it direction.  Prob2withsamemonth = 1 - Probwithalldifferentmonth.  Probwithalldifferentmonth(n people) = $(12\*...\*(12 -n))/12^n = \frac{12!}{(12-n)!*12^n}$.  Set to .5 and solve for n.

Comment: Well I just thought there would be also a way to compute this though combinatorics.